# Вставить текст в тег , elem.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Я знаю, что это может быть просто, но я не могу понять. Я пытаюсь взять текст c `<header id="headerS">`
и вставить в `<section id="main">`

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('headerS');
elem.innetHTML = ' '
// Cappuccino Company
```

```html
<header id="headerS">
  Cappuccino Company
  <a href="№"><img src="logo.src" alt=""></a>
</header>

<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="/history">History</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="/about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>

<section id="main"></section>
<footer id="footer">©<i>AroundTheWorld</i></footer>
```

Comment: вам надо вставить начинку из `header` в `section` или что? очень непонятно написали в приложении к приведенному коду

Comment: текст с header "Cappuccino Company" вставить в section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = document.getElementById('headerS').textContent;
```

```html
<header id="headerS">
  Cappuccino Company
  <a href="№"><img src="logo.src" alt=""></a>
</header>

<aside>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="/history">History</a></li>
    <li><a HREF="/about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>

<section id="main"></section>
<footer id="footer">©<i>AroundTheWorld</i></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете обернуть необходимый текст в тег и задать ему id, по которому обратитесь внутри скрипта

```
<header id="headerS">
  <div id='header'>Cappuccino Company</div>
  <a href="№"><img src="logo.src" alt=""></a>
</header>
```

В скрипте Вы заменяете имеющийся section.innerHTML на тот же section.innerHTML но с добавленной строчкой в начале.

```
let elem = document.getElementById('header');
let section = document.getElementById('main');
section.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + section.innerHTML;
```

Comment: да, но мне нужно взять текст с <header id="headerS"> и вставить в <section id="main">. Ваш код всталяет его в начало

Comment: Поправил в соответствии с Вашим комментарием